# Error when using two lists in Mapply on a Custom Function - Date Error

Tags: r, mapply

I'm trying to use a custom function and mapply to run through an inventory calculation count for those with (and without) laptops - the dates are stored in a list, as are the same amount of Yes.  The df has four columns - ID_Number, Order_Start_Date, Has_Equipment_Installed and Location

When I check `class(df$Order_Start_Date)` it comes up as date, but the function continues to throw an error when applied with two lists.  Hard coded variables work, but I want to try and use lists to run through the function to avoid repetition.  Any advice?

```
date_intervals <- list("2021-02-03", "2022-02-03", "2022-01-27","2022-01-06")
yes_intervals <- list("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes")


equipment_calculation_overall <- function(datevariant,
                                          yes_no)
  {equipment_calculation <- df %>% filter(df$Order_Start_Date <= as.Date(datevariant))
   equipment_calculation <- equipment_calculation %>% filter(grepl(yes_no, 
   equipment_calculation$Has_Equipment_Installed))
   equipment_calculation <- nrow(equipment_calculation)
    return(equipment_calculation)}

inventory_staff_total_with_laptop <- mapply(equipment_calculation_overall(date_intervals, yes_intervals))


Error in as.Date.default(datevariant) : 
  do not know how to convert 'datevariant' to class “Date”
```

Comment: That's not how you use `mapply`. Try `mapply(equipment_calculation_overall, datevariant = date_intervals, yes_no = yes_intervals, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`

Comment: Thank you, it's my first time using mapply - it's working, many thanks